# Cocos2dx 3.x button sprite [C++]

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I can't find a way to load the button image from a given .plist file instead of a plain texture.
Using

```
Button::create("normal_image.png", "selected_image.png", "disabled_image.png");
//or
button->loadTextures("normal_image.png", "selected_image.png", "disabled_image.png");
```

Search for a png and not use the sprite file in the cache.

I just want to put a sprite instead of a png. The `Button` class is working well, and it's the best solution for my actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass a TextureResType

```
Button::create("normal_image.png", "selected_image.png", "disabled_image.png", TextureResType::PLIST);
```

or

```
button->loadTextures("normal_image.png", "selected_image.png", "disabled_image.png", TextureResType::PLIST);
```

Comment: Thanks that seems the correct solution. Where can I found a complete Documentation for Cocos2DX 3.x??

Comment: Documentation for cocos2d-x 3.4 : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.4/index.html     UIButton : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.4/d2/db1/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_button.html#a30d06f9e4cd396f0311efa9b773d0cb3

Answer (score 0):

Ok before create the button first you need to make sure that you load the plist otherwise it will not work. Ok now lets create a simple button.

Let's load the plist file.

```
"AppDelegate.cpp"
SpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("yourSprites.plist");


"PauseLayer.h"
 #ifndef LEVELCHOOSER_H_
 #define LEVELCHOOSER_H_

 #include "cocos2d.h"
 #include "Popup.h"

 using namespace cocos2d;

 class LevelChooser:public cocos2d::Layer
{
Size s;
Popup *popup;
cocos2d::MenuItemSprite *pauseButton;
public:
virtual bool init();
virtual void showPopup(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
virtual void closePopup(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
virtual void playGame(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
virtual void playTimeGame(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
CREATE_FUNC(LevelChooser);
};

#endif /* LEVELCHOOSER_H_ */
```

Then load the button.
in the source file.

```
    "LevelChooser.cpp"
bool LevelChoser()
{
 Size s = Director::getInstance->getWinSize();
 pauseButton = MenuItemSprite::create(
        Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("ButtonPauseNormal.png"), "ButtonPauseActive.png", this,
        menu_selector(LevelChooser::showPopup));
 pauseButton->setPosition(s.width/2,s.heigh/2);
 return true;
}
void LevelChooser::showPopup(cocos2d::Ref* pSender)
{
//do Something
}
```

I hope you understand this well, anything just write a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. 
So I have to use a MenuItemSprite instead of a Button?
Because the signature for Button construct doesn't allow me to pass a Sprite.

Comment: I can't use the MenuItem like the button. For istance the callback function were called only on "touch Up". I wan't to call a function when the button is pressed

Comment: Oh so you're using the the ui::Button class ? Because that class have everything that you need. Maybe share more of your code